# Create a Related Product Rule -EE 2.3

Tags: magento2

I am trying to Create a Related Product Rule but when I get to the step of select specific Attribute set (like color) I don't see it as an option of other  Attribute but only Attribute Set is Default.

I have seen on places I can select from all kind of Attribute but I just not getting it.

https://prnt.sc/n0clo1

https://prnt.sc/n0cm56

You can see I don't have the option of all the Attribute like color, size...
You can see I don't have the option of all the Attribute like color, size...

what will help me to make a new attribute set? i need to use the attribute that in the attribute set like color, size.... like this: https://prnt.sc/n0vnbu
what i am getting is this (when i have colors, size in the "Attribute set") https://prnt.sc/n0cm56

Comment: attributes are not attribute-sets. attribute-sets are collections of attributes a product has

Comment: If you want to create any product rule based on the attribute set then you need to create a new attribute set for it.

Comment: what will help me to make a new attribute set? i need to use the attribute that in the attribute set like color, size....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1> You need to create product attributes like color, size...Assign them to products by attribute set (i think you did this)

2> You need to enable that attributes for promotion rule conditions: Attribute settings => Storefront properties => Use for Promo Rule Conditions = Yes